# PartialView rendering on new page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my Parent view called CreateAdmin I have some Html Controls, button and a div place holder for partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
    <p style="padding-left: 920px;">
        <button name="button" value="search" id="SearchResultbtn">
        Search</button>
    </p>
    <div class="editor-field" id="searchResult">
        //place holder for the partial view
    </div>
}
```

when clicked on button "Search" the partial view should be rendered dynamically inside this

```
<div id="searchResult"><div>
```

the jquery for this is

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SearchResultbtn").click(function () {
        $.get('/Views/Shared/_AdminSearchResult.cshtml', function (data) {
            $('#searchResult').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

My controller method is

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateAdmin(string button, Administration admin)
    {
        if (button == "search")
        {
            var result = Administration.GetAdministrationList();
            if (result.Count() != 0)
                return PartialView("_AdminSearchResult", result);
        }
    }
```

I have my partial view in shared folder name is _AdminSearchResult.cshtml.

The problem is that the partial view is being render in a new page instead of the place where it is suppose to. Can someone please point out where am i going worng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should read something along these lines:

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#SearchResultbtn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#searchResult").load('@Url.Action("CreateAdmin")');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Moby. It still opens in a new page.

Comment: Forgot about the new page business, updated code above might sort it.

Comment: This worked. Thanks Moby. Now there is this second issue. I am explicitly telling my controller method to open partial view.... return PartialView("_AdminSearchResult", result); instead in the id="searchResult" tag I am getting my main view...??

Comment: Put @{ Layout = null; } into the partial.

Comment: My pleasure. Good job on the question by the way, made it very clear and easy to diagnose.