# Partial view rendering in new page while paging using Pagedlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

Continuation of 
[PartialView rendering on new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889007/partialview-rendering-on-new-page)
So after fixing the above issue I added paging.

My controller method that handles partial view and paging is

```
public ActionResult CreateAdmin(string sortOrder, int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = 1;
        if (page != null)
            pageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(page);

        var result = SortResult(sortOrder);

        return PartialView("AdminSearchResult", result.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

In my partial view I am passing

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyApplication.Models.Administration>
```

The jquery for dynamically rendering partial view is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#SearchResultbtn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#searchResult").load('@Url.Action("AdminSearchResult", "Administration")');
    });
});
```

My view is just a table as shown below

```
<table class="searchResult" border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "AdminSearchResult", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastNameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, @class = "linkClicked" })
            </th>
            <th>
                Middle Name
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("First Name", "AdminSearchResult", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="parent">                    
                <td>
                    @item.LastName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.MiddleName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.FirstName
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

My paging and sorting is working fine. The issue is that when I click the ActionLink of "First Name" or any hearder for sorting the whole partial view is rendered in new page.

My guess is that the jquery needs to be updated but how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the behaviour you mentioned, I'm thinking you simply need something like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("First Name", "AdminSearchResult", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "searchResult" }, null)
```

Basically to do a partial update of the page, not a full page refresh?

To use the ajax methods successfully in MVC, you will need to do the following. Add this key to appsettings in web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

As well as include the unobtrusive ajax script:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Moby. Thanks for the reply again. Not it did not work. When I click "First Name" for sorting the partial view opens in new page.

Comment: Do you have unobtrusive AJAX or MVC Ajax as script includes on that page?

Comment: No i dont. Should I include it??

Comment: Yes, you need it to use the AJAX helpers in MVC. I updated my answer for you.

Comment: oh i see. So adding the above mentioned setting is same as putting the controls in Updatepanel for partial updates in asp.net???..

Comment: Somewhat, yes. It basically enables the baked in AJAX helpers (@Ajax.Actionlink, @Ajax.BeginForm etc) we use for forms, links and buttons in pursuit of partial page updates. It's more manual than UpdatePanels, but also far less confusing IMHO.

Comment: Well I already had <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /> in my app setting. I added the script <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in my view. Now I keep getting the jquery error on every postback "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you have included and do you have jQuery included first, then everything else? It would be useful to see your <head> tag. Also, open it in Chrome and use the inspector to find where the error is happening.

Comment: Thanks you so much for helping me out. I have just started working on MVC and Jquery so everything is new to me. Anyways back to the issue when i inspect I c these jquery in my header  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"/>

Comment: Oooh, you have two jquery references there, one 1.4.4 and one 1.9.1. Also, which version is that jQuery UI? Remove 1.4.4 and move 1.9.1 up to the top of those references. Is the unobtrusive reference above or below this snippet?

Comment: Ok removed 1.4.4 and moved 1.9.1 at the top. The jquery UI version is jQuery UI - v1.10.2 and unobtrusive reference is below the snippet

Comment: Ok you are genius. All that was needed, was to remove 1.4.4. jquery drives me insane. I still don't understand why having two version throwing an error.

Comment: Because they were fighting to extend the same object (jQuery/$) in differing ways. Glad you're sorted. Good luck with the rest of your app!

Comment: @user2225604 **[You can check here as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15921594/2007801)**