# Remote action method not being hit using jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I am using `ASP.NET MVC4` and `jQuery Validate` and `jQuery Validate unobtrusive`.

I have various elements on my form, but I only need to have one element validated. The other elements **DO NOT** need to be validated. Basically what happens is I have a textbox that accepts a number, and a button (**NOT** to submit the form) that takes the number in this texbox and does a remote call to check if the number exists, if not then it must display an error message.

My view's code:

```
<td class="edit-label">Change Control ID/Incident Number: <span class="required">**</span></td>
<td>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ChangeIncidentNumber)
     <button id="verifyButton" type="button">Verify</button>
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ChangeIncidentNumber)
</td>
```

My view model:

```
public class SearchServerViewModel
{
     // Partial view model

     public string ChangeIncidentNumber { get; set; }
}
```

My HTML output for the textbox:

```
<td class="edit-label">Change Control ID/Incident Number: <span class="required">**</span></td>
<td>
     <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="ChangeIncidentNumber" name="ChangeIncidentNumber" type="text" value="792952" />
     <button id="verifyButton" type="button">Verify</button>
     <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ChangeIncidentNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</td>
```

My jQuery code:

```
<script src="/Assets/JavaScripts/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Assets/JavaScripts/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<script>

     $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#ChangeIncidentNumber").validate({
               rules: {
                    ChangeIncidentNumber: {
                         required: true,
                         remote: '/Server/ValidateChangeIncidentNumber'
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                     ChangeIncidentNumber: {
                          required: "Required",
                          remote: "custom message:"
                     }
                }
          });

          $('#verifyButton').click(function () {
               var isValid = $('#ChangeIncidentNumber').valid();
          });
     });

</script>
```

My action method:

```
public ActionResult ValidateChangeIncidentNumber(string ChangeIncidentNumber)
{
     // Do whatever needs to be done

     return Json("Test error text", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In my web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

The required part works, it displays the Required message if the textbox is empty.  But if there is a value it is not hitting my action method.  Not sure why?

Comment: Did you try the **[Post Method as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15921594/2007801)** ?

Answer (score 0):

Calling validate() after including the unobtrusive plugin script does nothing, it just returns the validator instance created by the unobtrusive plugin.  The only reason that the required rule is working is because you have a [Required] attribute on the **ChangeIncidentNumber** field.  You can see this by the **data-val-required="Required"** in the rendered text box.

Is there a [Remote] data annotation attribute?  I think you need to investigate that.

Comment: I don't use data annotations.

Comment: ah well, ok so fluent validation or some other way, same answer applies - calling validate(...options...) after the unobtrusive plugin won't apply your options

Comment: Cool, but how would you do it then? Have you got a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

> I have various elements on my form, but I only need to have one
>   element validated. The other elements DO NOT need to be validated

Then set required or custom attribute for only those fields which are required to be validated.

**HTML**

```
<div id="formContainer" 
     data-url="@Url.Action("Action Name", "Controller Name", 
     new { area = "Area Name" })"></div>

<input id="BTN" type="button" value="Button" />
```

**JQuery (The below request can have get /post /getJSON. So change it accordingly)**

```
$('#BTN').click(function () {
    var $formContainer = $('#formContainer');
    var url = $formContainer.attr('data-url');
    $formContainer.load(url, function () {
        var $form = $('#myForm');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
        $form.submit(function () { //Here modification can be buton click                
            var $form = $(this);
            if ($form.valid()) {
                $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                    $form.html(data);
                    $form.removeData('validator');
                    $form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I did set it that it only validates the textbox. What is different from your and my code? I see you have a form submit?? I'm not submitting a form, just a textbox's value.